# Visual Studio intellisense filtering

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Hey does anyone know if theres a way in Visual Studio to filter the intellisense dropdown list based on what you have already typed.

e.g. say under MultiScaleImage there is a UseSprings property. I type in msi.springs and in the intellisense menu it would filter out anything that does not contain springs.

Flash Develop has this functionality and I found it extremely useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Resharper.  It adds much improved intellisense to VS and many many other features.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 3):

I belive that Visual Studio 2010 will have  intellisense improvements which will give it the ability to better filter type and member code completion than prior versions. You read more about on [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/22/vs-2010-code-intellisense-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx). I do not belive that the current versions will give you the level of filtering that you are looking for.

Comment: Even VS 11 doesn't provide filtering! ARGH! Filtering was supposed to be in VS 2005.  Sometimes, I just want to see events.  Oh well... start scrolling!